# ASP.NET CORE Controller gets null value from input setting value via JS/JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-core

I have a post controller to which I want to pass value set with JS or JQuery. So in my JS file I'm trying this before submit:

```js
function anullUser() {
    $("#Mod").val("2");
    $("#depForm").submit();
}
```

```html
@{
  @model IndexViewModel
}
<form id="depForm" class="formAddDepart" method="post">
<fieldset>
   /.../
  <input type="text" asp-for="Mod" />
</fieldset>
<div class="text-center">
  <button class="btn btn-warning" onclick="anullUser()" type="button">JS FUNC CALL</button>
</div>
```

Controller code:

```
public IActionResult Users(IndexViewModel model)
{ if(model.Mod == 2) { /.../} else {/.../} }
```

But in my controller I'm still getting NULL value for this property. I even have tried to do it and set this field with AJAX and still.

UPDATE:
asp-for attribute generates for me ID and NAME attributes.

Comment: Unless `asp-for="Mod"` generates `id="Mod"`, then you are missing that on your element

Comment: 1) check the *rendered* HTML (how it appears in the browser).  2) What's your controller/post action definition?  3) check the *network* tab in the browser to see exactly what's being sent.

Comment: I shared my code sample to help show you my idea better. If I misunderstood your requirement, pls update your question.

Answer (score 0):

Pls allow me show you a sample:

```
@model WebAppMvc.Models.UserModel

<form id="depForm" method="post" asp-action="Create">
    <div>
        <label asp-for="id" class="control-label" >id:</label>
        <input asp-for="id" class="form-control" type="text" />
    </div>
    <div>
        <label asp-for="name" class="control-label">name:</label>
        <input asp-for="name" class="form-control" type="text" />
    </div>
     <button class="btn btn-warning" onclick="anullUser()" type="button">JS FUNC CALL</button>
</form>

@section Scripts{
    <script>
        function anullUser(){
            $("#name").val("2");
            alert(11);
            $("#depForm").submit();
        }

    </script>
}
```

In my sample, I had a model which contain `id and  name` properties, so `asp-for="id"` will add attribute `id="id" name="id"` for the input. Then I had a post action in my controller which name is `Create` so I have to add `asp-action="Create"` in the `<form>`, if missing `asp-action`, no request will be send to the controller.

Then here's my Controller:

```
public class DataController : Controller
    {
        public IActionResult Index()
        {
            return View();
        }

        [HttpPost]
        public IActionResult Create(int id, string name) {
            return Ok();
        }
    }
```

[image]